# What to do when a person becomes uncomfortable when we want to help

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

I tried to help someone who had a problem of configuration in his system (Microsoft dotnet core technologies + Internet Information Services, IIS in short)

I just asked him a question about the content of a file and he started being unpleasant because he thought my question was out of scope (for him, the file was not needed). I just told him he needed this file and gave him a link (the documentation from Microsoft).

The guy started to tell me I didn't know the technology and I should try a "beginner" project to learn what I was talking about.

I stopped to comment his question.

What we should do when this happens?

Comment: Pretty much what you did: you walk away. You can and should flag the comments as well

Comment: You are not getting very good advice.  Walking away only multiplies the toxicity of such comments, we can't normalize the lousy behavior of one user preventing others from getting help with their questions.  It just isn't necessary, please flag such comments as rude in the future.

Comment: @HansPassant flag the comments as rude and then what? If the OP isn't willing to clarify the question, then moving on seems like the best option.

Comment: flagging rude comments is required so if this user has a pattern of insulting everyone, they get banned after a while. Then you can move on. Think of others :)

Comment: Flagging is ideal but walking away is still good advice, @HansPassant. Please don't confuse people into thinking they should do one or the other.

Comment: extra points for _not_ linking to the offending question just to have meta-crowd step-in. I don't know if I would have resisted it...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439466/asp-net-core-webapi-will-not-run-in-windows-ten)

Comment: Lol, reminds me of that punjabi guy in javascript.

Comment: although the OP was a bit rude and didn't react well to assistance, why was the question downvoted? To me it looks like the OP asked a well-though out, researched question

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - looks like the META effect happened anyway...but to me it seems like a reasonable question...

Comment: a lot of images, a bit long, but not worth all those downvotes...

Comment: @mcalex But... why?

Comment: Who cares.  Let it sink to the bottom.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

**Move on.** Invest your energy elsewhere to someone more receptive. Go out. Have a beer or chill with friends. Open a book. Discover one new thing. Stare at the sky. Stare at the wall. Wonder how a grandfather clock actually works and why it is called that way. Try to distinguish individual pixels on your screen. Nap. Nap again. Make yourself a veggie snack. Make yourself a meaty snack. Dance. Sing. Start writing a book. Give up writing a book. Hit up WorldBuilding.SE and spend the whole day on it. Work toward this C# bronze badge. Try Triage. Don't try Triage. Get a coffee. Plan a trip. Learn a new language. Learn a new programming language. Read Skeptics. Read about post-truth. Blame it all on someone. Change your world view. Get in touch with your local representative. Get involved in politics. Give up on politics. Experience something you loved as a kid. Get some ice cream. Hug someone. Pick a favourite baby animal. Hug the baby animal. Look closely at something mundane and discover something fascinating about it. Plant a tree. Reach out to someone you haven't talked to in 10 years. Teach. Love.

Enjoy life =)

Comment: This is a good list, especially "read skeptics" :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/5giWfpANMac

Comment: And the recommendation for [vegemite](https://vegemite.com.au/) :-)

Comment: you forgot "Be nice" :)

Comment: Great advice. We, programmers, too frequently overthink unimportant things, like worrying about trying to help unappreciative people who don't want to be helped.

Comment: I'm going to bookmark this answer so that I can read it whenever I am frustrated with literally anything anywhere.

Comment: WorldBuilding.SE is like that park near the office you go to when you want to let off some steam. You relax there and stop thinking about the bug you were fixing. You think about many things, from mundane ones like what to eat for dinner tonight, to deep ones like our place as a species in the cosmos. While mulling yourself over this thoughts, a talking, clothed White Rabbit looking intently at his pocket watch suddenly runs past you. Curious, you followed the rabbit around the park and into a hole where... Oh what were we talking about again?

Answer (score 47):

Not as fun as Paul answer, but at least short:

- downvote if the question is bad (besides being unclear)
- flag comments (only if really rude)
- flag/vote as "unclear" (since OP mind is set on not clarifying more)
- this ship has sailed: close this window / refresh to get an updated list of better questions

Comment: Downvoting a post based on a comment is probably going down the wrong path. Does it stop at that post? How many of that user's posts would you downvote based on not liking some of their comments? The point I am making here is that it is generally not the case where the post should be downvoted solely because of a disagreement in comments, revenge downvoting is rather frowned upon.

Comment: it's not a matter of revenge. The question is bad and comments tell us that it won't be improved since OP doesn't want to understand, so the downvote is needed to indicate the bad quality of the question.

Comment: Where does it state the question was bad here?

Comment: okay, fair enough. I don't want to convey the idea of revenge downvoting at all. That wasn't my idea. It's just that a lot of unclear questions are also bad. So it depends.

Comment: My whole issue was with the blanket statement of the downvoting, I like your edit, thanks :)

Comment: FWIW I sometimes refrain from downvoting and vote-to-closing while I endeavour to help OP. If the OP hasn't responded in a timely manner, or is unreceptive, then I'll follow any actions I'd have taken (typically dv and vtc) and [move on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368288/4143855), so for me, once I'd given up then that would be the time to downvote + vote to close

Comment: FYI: the downvote arrow reads "This question does not...; **it is unclear**...". So yes, **downvote unclear questions**. A good question cannot be also unclear