# Learning the art of not replying - how to be more welcoming

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, welcoming, rude-or-abusive

We're [still adjusting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming) to the upheavals and site examination since Jay Hanlon's "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming" blog.

There's some confusion about what is [rude or polite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368538/what-have-i-done-wrong-considering-rudeness-politeness) and a moving focus on [how our site is performing under new scrutiny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368511/are-there-trends-towards-being-more-welcoming.). There's been an increase in comment flags.

One simple trick that helps is not replying. There is no onus to reply when leaving a comment. If you've left a comment asking for clarification and the OP then responds by starting an argument, don't reply.

#### Don't argue in comments

There's no point in arguing in the comments. It's better to leave one well crafted comment than 4 or 5 comments that gradually deteriorate as the OP fails to take well-meaning advice. What's worse is when those comments are flagged and deleted. If there is a pattern of user comments being flagged and deleted as abusive, it [raises an automatic flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284053/community-deletion-of-comments-should-raise-a-moderator-flag) for mods and frequently will result in a mod message, which can lead to suspensions.

#### Put helpful or constructive first.

[Brutal honesty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315122/3956566) is not helpful if you don't consider there's a person at the other end of the keyboard. So honest feedback combined with helpfulness is the recipe needed for [successful comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

#### When to comment.

1. Do you intend to be helpful, wanting to advise the OP on how to improve their post? Yes, proceed to step 2.
2. Is your comment professional and clear?  Yes, proceed to step 3.
3. Post the comment.

#### If the OP replies.

1. Is the OP asking for advice on how to improve that you haven't included? Yes, proceed to step 4. No, proceed to step 2.
2. Is the OP arguing with you? Yes. proceed to step 3.
3. Is the OP aggressive/rude/belligerent? Flag the comment and proceed to "when not to comment".
4. Do you have time and patience to respond and are interested in helping the OP? Yes, refer to "when to comment". No, refer to "when not to comment".

#### When not to comment.

1. When you're time poor and/or feeling impatient.
2. When the comment is sarcastic.
3. When someone is arguing with you.
4. When the [OP tells you to stop commenting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368288/3956566).
5. When you don't feel like commenting.
6. When you feel annoyance at being pinged.
7. When another user has already said what you plan to say.

It's human nature to respond to pings, social media relies upon it. But it's ok to ignore comment replies. We're all volunteers here and your time is valuable. Help when you can, and if it becomes an annoyance feel free to walk away. If a comment is rude, flag it, do not respond.

#### Repetition in comments

The other thing is, when we see somebody doing something wrong, we want to say "hey that's not right". If someone has already said that, you don't need to repeat it. It needs to be said once. If anyone becomes abusive in the comments, do not reply. When someone is angry, [arguing with them will invariably not end well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anger#Psychology_and_sociology). Flag and move on.

#### We're being nice, not accepting poor quality content

There is fear that being nice and tolerant is going to keep [poor quality content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/low-quality-posts) on the site. If a post is low quality, it shouldn't stay on the site. Being nice and welcoming people onto the site comes with our attitudes when we communicate with the newcomer. Deleting poor quality content, for better or worse, is something all users need to accept. If the post is not up to scratch, it will be removed.

Don't let a fear based on the need to moderate content or a loss of community input into content moderation, drive you to continue replying in comments beyond what is helpful. We can offer tips and advice,  but it is ultimately up to each person to improve their own content and that's what flags and votes (especially close votes and delete votes) are for. We can only do so much as a community, and it's important we conserve our efforts. In doing so, we can actually improve how welcoming we are perceived to be. In other words, less is sometimes more when it comes to commenting.

Comment: I think we need a flow chart for the sections with the enumerations :)

Comment: _"Is the OP arguing with you?"_ -> No, .....

Comment: When the OP is arguing with you... maybe add "do they get aggressive/rude/belligerent? Flag". We've all seen the ones that get belligerent. I feel it's a broken window if you let such comments stay.

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes, good advice.

Comment: Are we still blaming the comment feature for all unwelcomingness?

Comment: @mario if you're not going to write a constructive comment, why write at all? Do you think that a sarcastic comment like that is in any way helpful? What are you trying to achieve by that comment?

Comment: @mario - comments is just one area where SO is perceived as being unwelcoming. The fact that there are other areas to address doesn't stop us wanting to address this one. Sorting it out won't make SO welcoming all by itself, but it will help.

Comment: I just find it odd that we're still waxing about this. To me crude comments are a symptom at best. -- And for some reason we completely skipped this years "Newbies.SO" proposal; which would easily fix the perceived rudeness woe.

Comment: @mario I totally agree re Newbies.SO. I proposed it myself. They clearly don't want it. It's hard to be inclusive of all skill levels. Unless we introduce a beginner tag. Anyway this post is in response to the increase in comment flags and what can be done to help this.

Comment: I feel like we've already had part of this discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367388/7296893), but that got deleted...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth not at all, this is dealing specifically with comments and what is being flagged and why. I didn't delete that. Tim Post did.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment. I'm missing the step explaining what to do when the OP is not arguing. (probably move to step 4 or when to comment)

Comment: @YvetteColomb It's both about when to comment and when not to (at least how I interpret it). The scope is just a bit more narrow on this question.

Comment: @AndréKool yep.

Comment: One great tip which I recommend is to *upvote* existing comments instead of repeating advice. This reinforcement of an existing view saves your time and indicates to OP a comment which they should note. If, however, you have the urge to upvote a sarcastic comment, hold back, think again, and maybe click on flag instead.

Comment: Post deleted, undeleted...admit it, you're just trolling now ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak [I think we've been over this already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368100/moderator-repeatedly-deleting-and-undeleting-their-own-answers).

Comment: @AndrasDeak oops

Comment: @Dukeling that's exactly what I was referring to :P

Comment: Part of the problem is that genuinely helpful comments are perceived as _"attacking the OP"_, by some askers. There's no way around that.

Comment: People leave rude comments because they're frustrated. They're frustrated because too many people who can't construct good questions ask here, and assume either that they can, or that they *shouldn't* have to. People who can't construct good questions ask here because (1) at no point are they told that maybe their question won't be accepted, (2) they *do* get answers sometimes, (3) maybe they don't know about the alternatives and (4) asking on [so] is easy. Getting (the Meta-reading subset of) people to write less unwelcoming comments is treating the symptom instead of the disease.

Comment: @Dukeling I agree. Which is why we have to work hard and moving on and flag or close vote poor posts

Comment: @Dukeling, Closing unclear / broad questions **in a timely manner** is a huge problem. Fixing it will solve many of the issues you describe. DV + comment is great, but in my opinion VTC should be the *first* port of call. Too often I hear users say, "I DV & commented, but I didn't think the question was bad enough to VTC." My *default* practice is VTC before going any further.

Comment: Why exactly shouldn't we comment _"When someone is arguing with you."_? I think an (polite and constructive) argument can be helpfull for a post.

Comment: @mario Newbies.SO would probably be little more than a dumping ground for terrible questions (which is not necessarily to say I'm not in support of it). The problem with most questions isn't really that the asker doesn't know much about programming, it's that they don't know much about asking good questions, and moving a bad question to a different site wouldn't make it any less bad. Although being a good programmer and asking a good question does both require a lot of analytical and research ability.

Comment: @Dukeling TBH I'm also not convinced it would be a terribly good idea yet. Though my main concern would be such a segregated site drying out regular SO. (And let's be honest, we all *love* the occasional noob question:). Even if there was, say, quick/lively migration of →improve-worthy and ←improved questions between Newb.SO and Reg.SO

Comment: @AndréKool My usual take on this advice is "don't get mired in an *unproductive* argument". If the argument is made of polite, constructive messages that actually add something to the parent post, it is fine -- just a case of comments being used for what they are here for. (On a tangential note, this is one of the reasons why, while I think this post has good advice on comment overuse, I'm against proposals to severely curb comments or remove them altogether.)

Comment: I respectfully disagree that "Brutal honesty, is not helpful, if you don't consider there's a person at the other end of the keyboard. ". Brutal honesty is the **most** helpful thing that you can give to people. But there is a difference between being honest and being blunt. I don't think your post is explicit enough to advise as to which one you want. Do you want people to stop being blunt in their honesty or just stop being honest?

Comment: @EthanField I feel the following sentence in the question addresses this point: "So honest feedback combined with helpfulness is the recipe needed for successful comments."

Comment: @duplode Something blunt and/or rude can also be helpful. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @EthanField You have a point. However, if you have a comment which is both helpful and rude, *the rudeness itself is not helpful*, and could be done away with without compromising the helpfulness.

Comment: @duplode Which is why I'm saying that section of this post isn't explicit enough. It should say something to the effect of "If your comment is both honest and rude, ditch the rude bit.". Instead, we're encouraged to combine honesty with helpfulness, which sounds like pandering where we shouldn't need to. Honesty is typically implicitly helpful without having to add anything else.

Comment: @EthanField you're arguing semantics. Why don't you post this in an answer? It would be helpful

Comment: I'm totally on board with developing FAQ blueprints formulating "being nice" into a set of rules that are specific and detailed, yet don't feel like censorship and nanny-statery. This looks like a good step in that direction.

Comment: Perhaps, for the user frustrated by some low quality contribution, it is worth mentioning the correct, productive outlets for that frustration (flagging/downvoting/closevoting)

Comment: @Pekka웃 do you have the time to help draft an faq post? Or we could make this into a community wiki if you think it has the right skeleton. Thoughts?

Comment: Minor clarification: in the final paragraph, by "this fear based need to moderate content", do you mean the fear of being stopped from moderating the site, or the continued need to curate content? While I think both readings make sense, I feel it might be clearer to rephrase it as either "this fear" or "the need to moderate content", respectively, depending on the primarily intended meaning.

Comment: By the way: I agree with you about the paralysing fear, and see it as [a problem in and of itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367789/but-seriously-how-to-be-nice-when-trying-to-say-the-code-is-crap/367790?noredirect=1#comment588911_367790).

Comment: @duplode both really. I think people are worried they're being shut down and will lose their freedom to moderate and there's been this pressure for a long time to fight low quality posts. In that regard, it would be better if the community had sharper tools to deal with poor quality posts, rather than to fear a battle of getting them closed and/or deleted. That's why I've continued to post about this. Trying to point people into a solution that doesn't make people feel disenfranchised.

Comment: "Are we still blaming the comment feature for all unwelcomingness?" is a perfectly valid point, and not unhelpful. If you consider this to be too snarky, you're setting the bar extremely low.

Comment: @Cerbrus "genuinely helpful comments are perceived as 'attacking the OP', by some askers. There's no way around that." -- Indeed; there is only so much we can, or should, do. In spite of that, though, there is something to gain in curbing unhelpful comments, and in leaving out the unhelpful bits within otherwise helpful comments. It is not an all-or-nothing situation.

Comment: `do you have the time to help draft an faq post?` not at the moment, unfortunately, thanks to GDPR  will chime in when I can!

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've adopted this approach in my office: https://i0.wp.com/excelaccountantsltd.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/GDPR.jpg

Comment: @Clive https://twitter.com/erishabh/status/1000036964081561602

Comment: @m69 You say "**too** snarky", so I presume you realise that it is *at least a little* snarky, and some people are a lot more sensitive than others. I reckon it's fine on Meta, but on main we should try to keep things more professional and avoid snark altogether (is that the type of thing you'd say around or to your hypothetical uptight suit-wearing CEO?). It also doesn't say why it isn't to blame for all the unwelcomingness, or what is, so it doesn't give much in terms of actionable feedback, which would firmly put it in the "not constructive" category in my book.

Comment: @Dukeling Well, it says what it wants to say in a slighly roundabout way, so that's always open to (mis-) interpretation; but surely we can't ban all rhetorical devices from the language we use? There are only a handful of things besides comments which can make a new asker feel unwelcome: their question being completely ignored, getting answers that fall short of their expectation of SO as a free code-writing service, downvotes and close-votes; so it's not exactly unclear what is being alluded to, i.e. the problem lies as much with the new users themselves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Upvote existing comments

One way to improve the quality of a comments stream is to upvote an existing *helpful* comment which **materially aligns with your views** and omitting to comment yourself altogether. This is good practice for several reasons:

1. **Duplicate content does not add value**. This applies even to ephemeral content such as comments.
2. **Upvoting reinforces a single idea**. OP is more likely to react favourably to a single upvoted comment than a barrage of 10 similar comments with variations in wording.
3. **Comments are for clarification**. By upvoting a single comment, rather than many users adding similar comments, you are indicating a *community view* rather than instigating a one-on-one discussion.
4. **SO logic focuses on upvoted comments**. In a long thread where all comments are not shown by default, upvoted comments take precedence.
5. **Save your time**. It is a more productive use of volunteers' time to reinforce existing comments than to write new, similar ones.

Note that the comment you upvote does not have to be *identical* to what you might write yourself; it just needs to be materially aligned.

## But beware...

If you see a sarcastic, accusatory, snarky, or otherwise harmful comment which you agree with, consider moving your mouse a few pixels lower and click on the flag instead.

**Edit:** For the same reasons upvoting comments is helpful, flagging where appropriate is particularly important for highly upvoted comments.

Comment: Oh, yea, let's assume sarcasm is harmful / unhelpful.

Comment: To clarify: When the sarcasm is __glaringly obvious__, it _can help_ to make a point.

Comment: Hmm, not that this helps much.  I've been losing a lot of highly upvoted comments lately.  On this meta question as well.  Suppressing speech at meta is a very slippery slope.  Unfortunately that blasted blog post seemed to have empowered this kind of intolerance, hard to imagine that was the author's true intention.

Comment: @HansPassant: Obligatory _"We're less welcoming to experienced users now"_ comment.

Comment: @Cerbrus just give it some time, that post will appear sooner or later.

Comment: @Cerbrus sarcasm is never helpful and not welcome in comments. By definition: `Sarcasm : the use of irony to mock or convey contempt.` Not helpful. When some of the regulars who keep objecting to these types of posts understand that, we will have made progress. We're not less welcoming to experienced users, we don't want bad behaviour new or old and you call me out on my behaviour more than anyone, so how can you even use that argument?

Comment: I disagree, @YvetteColomb. Furthermore, blanket statements like that are _always false_.

Comment: Humour I hope?.

Comment: Why are you bringing up "us"? What does me disagreeing with you have to do with anything?

Comment: @Cerbrus because you're saying experienced users are being "mistreated", yet you are ok with examining my behaviour. What makes the experienced user sacrosanct against some review?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that site regulars are being accused of being unwelcoming all over meta, but newbies that _don't care_ or _can't handle criticism_ aren't even considered to be part of, or even at the root of, the problem. I am seeing a _lot_ more comments being removed after the "welcoming" debacle. Comments that are, at their core, harmless. But someone was "offended", so it got flagged.

Comment: @HansPassant don't worry about those virtual votes on your comments. Mods are not taking it upon themselves  to initiate deletion of  your comments, we're responding to flags. And if you take [this meta thrashing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365889/3956566) as a sample, with people going to meta to complain, you can see why we're erring on the side of deletion.

Comment: @Cerbrus many of us *have* been unwelcoming. I went through my comment history on main and was *yikes* we may mean well, but we can't afford to mistreat people. It's so simple. It's not about compromising quality, it's about removing snark and sarcasm. It doesn't mean we say "there there it's ok" we just give constructive feedback in a respectable manner. It doesn't matter what the other person does, we cannot lower ourselves to that level. You know how you feel when I react? Well none of us can react on the main site and especially not collectively. Flag and walk away.

Comment: Please don't presume to know how I feel when you react.

Comment: Also, @YvetteColomb: _"**When not to comment.**: 3. When someone is arguing with you."_ Please follow your own advice.

Comment: @Cerbrus well clearly you're not ok with it. That's all the blog is attempting (albeit in a clucksy way) to say. That we can do better.  It's not about shaming the community. Without the community there'd be no site. It's about taking stock, reflecting and asking, how can we improve. We have to, we're under public fire and the Network management is demanding it now. So it's something we need to work on as a team.

Comment: Yes, my _opinions_ are pretty clear. My _feelings_, on the other hand, are not something you can possibly be aware of.

Comment: @Cerbrus "When the sarcasm is glaringly obvious, it can help to make a point." -- Still, if the sarcasm is directed at the other party in the discussion, the point is being made at their expense. Granted, there are unproblematic uses of sarcasm which are wholly aimed at the matter being discussed, rather than at an interlocutor. I hazard, however, that they are the exception rather than the norm; and in any case it is generally easy to spot the difference.

Comment: @duplode: And that's why I think an all-out ban on sarcasm is a bad thing.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Nobody can ban sarcasm. In fact, neither is this possible, nor do I think this is what the community *wants*. But we can and should **consider** flagging where there is a mocking tone. It's easy to spot, usually the question is on -5, usually it's personal ("you" - not "this idea"), often it's a new user, sometimes there's an argument. I flag these as "Chatty, no longer required" rather than "Rude/Abusive".

Comment: @jpp: This answer is grouping sarcasm with _"accusatory, snarky, or otherwise harmful"_ comments and saying those should be flagged. I'm just saying we should be a little more context-aware than that.

Comment: @duplode I'd say sarcasm is always problematic because it's unprofessional (at the very least). As much as it's about not offending any single user, it's about the overall tone of the site (which, by itself, can make people feel less welcomed, can make others more comfortable with leaving or supporting problematic comments and affects how the rest of the world sees [so]). Not to mention that it could be hard for some to differentiate between acceptable and unacceptable uses of sarcasm.

Comment: @Dukeling: Unprofessional? Sarcasm is a form of ___art___. Practiced by many, mastered by few. I don't think it's true it's _always problematic"_

Comment: @Cerbrus Plenty of art wouldn't fit in a professional setting.

Comment: @Dukeling: I agree, but _"Plenty"_ is not _"All"_. I refer you to my [earlier comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368577/learning-the-art-of-not-replying-how-to-be-more-welcoming/368592#comment594718_368592): _"Furthermore, blanket statements like that are always false."_